# rust procedural macros, how to find an identifier?

Tags: rust, macros, metaprogramming

I am breaking my head against the wall trying to figure this one out.

What I want:

A procedural macro that replaces all tagged instances of an identifier with a pluralized version of the same word.

I have the macro itself set up:

```rust
extern crate proc_macro;

use syn::{parse_macro_input, DataEnum, DataUnion, DeriveInput, FieldsNamed, FieldsUnnamed};
use regex::Regex;

extern crate quote;

use proc_macro::TokenStream;

#[proc_macro]
pub fn pluralize(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream
{
    //let DeriveInput { ident, data, .. } = parse_macro_input!(input);

    return input;
}
```

I have done tests and it is getting called properly. I also have a function that uses regular expressions to find the tagged portions where replacement needs to happen.

```rust
    let input_str = input.to_string();

    let re_token = Regex::new(r"\[<.*s\s*>\]").unwrap();
    let re_name = Regex::new(r"\w+").unwrap();

    for m in re_token.find_iter(&input_str)
    {
         let name = re_name.find(m.as_str()).unwrap();
         println!("{}", m.as_str());
    }
```

All I need to make this work is to get the identifier from the TokenStream, and I cannot for the life of me figure out how.

Comment: `[<...>]` is not a valid identifier. Also, are you looking for `paste`?

Comment: I am replacing tokens that I pass to paste, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `syn`'s [`visit_mut`](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/visit_mut/index.html). Implement the [`VisitMut`](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/visit_mut/trait.VisitMut.html) trait and override [`visit_ident_mut()`](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/visit_mut/trait.VisitMut.html#method.visit_ident_mut).

However, this has two serious disadvantages:

1. It won't traverse macros.
2. It is hard to impossible to identify constructs such as `[< ... >]` which are not valid Rust constructs in this way.

And also, it pulls the heavy `syn` as a dependency, and even requires the `full` feature (and `visit-mut`).

A better way is to use `TokenStream` directly. Look for [`Group`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/proc_macro/struct.Group.html)s delimited with `[]`, and if they contain `<` and `>` as first and last tokens pluralize all identifiers. Recurse for groups. This can be something like:

```rust
fn process_token_stream(tokens: TokenStream, pluralize: bool) -> TokenStream {
    tokens
        .into_iter()
        .map(|token_tree| match token_tree {
            TokenTree::Ident(ident) if pluralize => {
                TokenTree::Ident(Ident::new(&(ident.to_string() + "s"), ident.span()))
            }
            TokenTree::Group(group) => {
                let mut pluralize = pluralize;
                let mut stream = VecDeque::from_iter(group.stream());
                let mut delimiter = group.delimiter();
                if group.delimiter() == Delimiter::Bracket {
                    if let (Some(TokenTree::Punct(first)), Some(TokenTree::Punct(last))) =
                        (stream.front(), stream.back())
                    {
                        if first.as_char() == '<' && last.as_char() == '>' {
                            pluralize = true;
                            stream.pop_front();
                            stream.pop_back();
                            delimiter = Delimiter::None;
                        }
                    }
                }

                let mut new_group = Group::new(
                    delimiter,
                    process_token_stream(TokenStream::from_iter(stream), pluralize),
                );
                new_group.set_span(group.span());
                TokenTree::Group(new_group)
            }
            other => other,
        })
        .collect()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bbca74dcc00750b23e718014eaea11ce).